# How to open WPS Write, Presentation and Spreadsheet application from Ubuntu Command ( Alt + F2)

Tags: ubuntu, wps

I want to open WPS applications like Write, Presentation and Spreadsheet using the Ubuntu Command Option i.e (Alt + F2)

Comment: this should be on [ubuntu.se]. Just find the binary name for those apps and run. Duplicate: [Is there a way to find the executable name for an application so I can launch it in a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/294203/253474)

Answer (score 0):

To Open WPS **Writer** Application use command : 
Alt + F2 -> **wps** (Enter)

To Open WPS **Spread Sheet** Application use command : 
Alt + F2 -> **et** (Enter)

To Open WPS **Presentaion** Application use command : 
Alt + F2 -> **wpp** (Enter)